# Can we have an option to sort suggested edits by type?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

Can we have an option to sort suggested edits by type?

- Tag only
- Tag wiki
- Tag excerpt

In this type of format in the close vote review queue:

[image]

This would help people trying to focus on misguided serial tag editors and plagiarism in tag wikis. On SO meta, [Let's Stop Tag Wiki Plagiarism](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313486/lets-stop-tag-wiki-plagiarism)