# Can we have tag wiki and wiki excerpt edit reviews in a separate queue to suggested edits?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

To approve tag wiki and wiki excerpts [requires 5k](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits).

To approve post edits [requires 2k](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).

Given there are issues concerning tag wiki edits:

[Let's stop tag wiki plagiarism](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313486/lets-stop-tag-wiki-plagiarism)

[Stopping tag wiki plagiarism, Part II: Taking Action](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318288/stopping-tag-wiki-plagiarism-part-ii-taking-action)

- The suggested edits queue is the only queue that has reviews for moderation privileges that requires varying reputation.
- Although it's another queue, it's a queue that could be cleared easily.
- The advantage is users could have a separate quota to review tag wikis, and reviewers can periodically check the queue to see if there are pending edits.
- As a side issue it may be easier to implement review bans or any other decisions that may be made down the track for reviewers approving copied content, etc.

Can we please have them in separate queues to make reviewing the tag wikis easier?

I've already requested [Can we have an option to sort suggested edits by type?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274190/can-we-have-an-option-to-sort-suggested-edits-by-type), but nothing has come of this, so I thought I'd see if the community would prefer a separate queue.

Comment: I think your filter suggestion is the best way to go.  I for one do not want another queue to have to look at.

Comment: @NathanOliver see my edit with advantages

Comment: I agree with this. Reviewing tag wikis require more from the reviewer than suggested edits to posts. Another idea is to also restrict wiki tag edits/reviews to those with a bronze/silver/gold badge in that tag, at least for very popular tags.

Comment: @Lundin let's see if this bounty makes a difference :/

Comment: filter suggestion on SO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345636/make-suggested-edits-queue-filterable-for-posts-vs-tag-wikis

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Separating tag wiki edits into a separate review queue will also allow us to enforce the different level of scrutiny required when reviewing these edits.

- Tag wikis are [especially prone to plagiarism](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=tag+wiki+plagiarism), and hence reviewers should search Google for exerpts from the edit to check that it is not plagiarised. In some cases, [bans apply for approving blatant plagiarism](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318288/4622463).
- Some sites also have a [specified standard format](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7845/104515) that tag wiki editors should follow, and non-compliant edits need to be rejected or improved to fit the correct format.
- Tag wikis are shown in many more places than standard posts, and hence edits to these wikis need to be of a higher standard than normal edits.

This information could be placed in the 'more info' dropdown when you are reviewing suggested tag wiki edits:

[image: Tag wiki review queue mockup]

And finally, we should be consistent. All the other review queues require a certain amount of reputation to review in. The suggested edits queue is the only queue with two levels of required reputation. It just makes more sense to separate them.